# ImageIcon is grayscale on JButton?

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

```
ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("resources/images/2Neighbours.png");
JButton newButton = new JButton(i);

ImageIcon j = new ImageIcon("resources/images/3Neighbours.png");
newButton.setIcon(j);
```

The .png files are coloured but when im running this in java, the images are grayscale?

Could it be because I have the JButton.setEnabled(false)?

![Running Code] https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oNMv.jpg

Comment: Hi. Please attach a screenshot.

Comment: Are the buttons enabled?  Do you have rollover images set?  Do you have some example code that we can actually run?

Comment: So try to change the parameter to "button.setEnableb(true)" and run your code again. If the images will be grayscale still, then it means that the question is worth to ask.